# Joined query, with group by and sub count based on a column

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table called `products`, my query retrieves distinct and grouped rows from it, grouped by product_type_id.
This is the query, and it works

```
SELECT p.*, count(p.id) as count, pt.name from products p
LEFT JOIN product_types pt on pt.id = p.product_type_id
where client_id = 777
group by product_type_id
```

However, it's not enough and i want a sub-count by the `activated` column (Boolean type) and the NOT-Activated column.

I'd like to get for each row, a sub-count of the products that are set as true, and those which are set as false. I'd like to get them as another column in the relevant row.

is it possible?

Comment: Sample data would help convey what you are doing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff hi, i can't see how it will help.. (i will add some now anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a BIT column type you may need to cast this into an integer.

I would suggest a CASE select statement, or a subselect.

ie,

**Activated**

```
sum(CAST(activated as INT)) as TotalActivated
```

or

```
(select sum(CAST(activated as INT)) FROM products WHERE product_type_id = p.product_type_id) as TotalActivated
```

**Not activated**

```
sum(case when activated = 1 then 0 else 1 end) as NotActivated
```

or

```
(select sum(case when activated = 1 then 0 else 1 end) FROM products WHERE product_type_id = p.product_type_id) as NotActivated
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a separate column with the count of `activated`, then you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select p.*, count(p.id) as count, pt.name,
       SUM(activated) as numActivated,
       (COUNT(*) - SUM(activated)) as numNotActivated
from products p left join
     product_types pt
     on pt.id = p.product_type_id
where client_id = 777
group by product_type_id;
```

MySQL treats booleans as integers in a numeric context, with 1 for true and 0 for false.  So, you can just add the values to get the count.

EDIT:

If you want separate rows, then include it in the `GROUP BY`:

```
select p.*, activated, count(p.id) as count, pt.name
from products p left join
     product_types pt
     on pt.id = p.product_type_id
where client_id = 777
group by product_type_id, activated;
```

Comment: thanks. I don't understand how to get the "not activated" , since the sum is 0 ... (o/c in the php i can to the math, but can it be done with SQL?)
(Now i saw that i asked only for the activated, sorry)